# icone não fica ao lado do input bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando por um icon ao lado do meu input usando bootstrap, porém ele sempre fica embaixo

Meu código está assim:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está faltando a div com a class `input-group`, veja como está o [exemplo](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) no site oficial do bootstrap versão 3:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

Comment: eu deixo essa div dentro de um formgroup ?

Answer (score 0):

Seu HTML parece correto. Fiz até [esse fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmkekc09/) para demonstrar.
Experimente com outros tamanhos de coluna, como `col-sm-12` e `col-lg-12`.

Outra possibilidade é que haja outros estilos em seus próprios arquivos CSS interferindo com os estilos do Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, acabei de resolver um problema de posicionamento com o bootstrap e era uma determinada classe no css do bootstrap . Te aconselho a alterar a classe do seu bootstrap . Eu vi que o padding da classe brand(Meu caso) tinha um determinado valor e coloquei para 0. Bem, o que você deve fazer, ao meu ver é pegar a classe que mexe com aquilo que está inconsistente no seu projeto e fazer as alterações manuais correspondente ao que você quer.